# Abort vs. Cancel Button: When do I use Abort, when Cancel?

Tags: button, translation

We need to translate some of our UI to English, and the question arises: When do I use "Abort", when "Cancel" as a button text? They seem rather interchangeable, and translate more or less to the same word in German (our source)... So, is there a difference? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my previous project we used the following:

- When some process is already started use `Abort`.
- If in this step the user can reject a (not yet started) operation use `Cancel`.

Also we use `Abort` when some problem is found.